# How to run a bash script from a browser?

Tags: bash, browser

I'm using mac and normally i just browse... but occasionally i have to do some tasks periodically.

yes, i could save a "xxx.command" script and double click to run it.

But just curious, is it possible to make a shortcut somewhere inside browser such as Google Chrome or safari, so that one click - and it will run?

Comment: That sounds like a huge security risk.

Comment: yes it is... but a lazy man wonders...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like I should submit my overly complicated to set up solution.

Have a web browser supporting php/python running as your user (unless it's user independent, then this is much easier). Serve the php/python files which will just open a shell and execute said command. Then store bookmarks in your browser bar.

```
<?PHP
`./myscript.sh`;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
In conkeror use M-! (alt-!) for Chrome and Safari google shell addons
```